# Sikuli Scripts not running if RDC is minimized

Tags: python, user-interface, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I have a sikuli script which does the Siebel Tools incremental Compilation Task on a Windows Box from Jenkins.

The problem is: When i run the task i always have to open the RDC window open for the task to be executed.As soon i minimize the window the script fails.

Hence if the Sikuli script is running i will not able to use my local system for any other task.

I found some posts on launchpad.net.
this is one reference: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/213636
 But it did not work.

Can anyone help on this.

Comment: This is a known issue for Sikuli. One solution is to use [SeeShell](https://a9t9.com/seeshell/), which does not have this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This solution has helped me out:**

Close all open Remote Desktop sessions.

Launch the Registry editor (regedit.exe).

Navigate to one of the following Registry keys, depending on whether you wish to modify the Remote Desktop settings only for the current user or for all users on the computer:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client

Create a DWORD value named RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized and set it to 2.

Close the Registry Editor.

**After these steps are done RDC when minimized will not be suppressed and sikuli will work.**

***Answer taken from:***
https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/in-minimized-window.html

---

Other solution is to use VNC connection instead of RDC. RealVNC for example.
You setup VNC server on machine that sikuli scripts are running on and connect from your other machine. You should even be able to close the connection window and scripts should still be able to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep the RDC session running in the background. Just don't minimize it. I am doing the same with my tests.

Comment: But how to send the active RDC to background?

Comment: Where's your sikuli script running in? Local machine or in the Remote desktop machine?